# Access my Android's file system without a data cable

Tags: android, cross-platform, file-synchronization

When I connect my Android phone using a data cable (in USB mode), I see it mounted as an external storage device. To which I can make any changes that I want (cut/copy/paste/save files from my computer).

Is there any app which lets me do this (sync the file system), without a data cable (through WiFi)?

I am looking for something similar to Dropbox, but for the entire Android file system (including SD card) not just a single folder.

Is there any app out there which fulfills these requirements?

I would like the desktop app to be cross platform, but windows only is fine too.

**P.S.** I am aware of Airdroid and others like it which let me access the file system from the browser. But I would prefer to have the Android filesystem as a folder on my HDD, not inside a browser.

Comment: You cannot have it both ways if you want it to display as a folder in HDD then by definition it must be mounted. Dropbox merely syncs a local folder in your PC & Phone while your Android Filesystem is a different matter altogether which cannot & should not be synced as you are asking.

Comment: I use mounted in the loosest sense of the word. Dropbox like syncing will suffice.

Comment: So am I correct in assuming you are looking for a shared folder which in this case is your entire android filesystem where you make changes & it gets reflected on device?

Comment: @RamGAthreya Yes. If not all of the filesystem then atleast most of it (leaving out hidden/system folders if required)

Comment: What OS(es) do you want to access your device from?

Comment: I use all 3 (Mac, Windows and Linux).

But if it works on any one that will be great...

Answer (score 3):

**[GoodSync desktop](http://www.goodsync.com/)  and [GoodSync Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siber.gsserver)  App is your answer.**

Provides a variety of options and available on multiple platforms. It has many features (*some need the paid pro version which I haven't tried* ) but I only used a few personally.

Main features:

1. Synchronize Files
2. Backup Files
3. Direct P2P Sync
4. Not forgetting, all is wireless.

> GoodSync syncs files between your computer, mobile devices, FTP, SFTP,
>   Amazon S3, Google Drive, SkyDrive, WebDAV, Azure
>
> GoodSync backs up files to portable drives, mobile devices and to FTP,
>   S3, GDocs, SkyDrive, DAV or another computer.
>
> GoodSync is very fast and syncs files on your command, periodically,
>   by a schedule or in real time (on file change).

Available on:

- Windows + 2Go USB version
- Mac + 2Go USB version
- Android
- IOS
- Unix/Linux

I used it mainly to sync between my Windows PC and a remote FTP server (or another pc). I don't have that much experience with the mobile version, I tried it before and it worked exactly the same as if I was syncing between two desktops.

Here, I just made those screenshots, it should give you an idea.

You select a *Left Side* device:
Here you can see it managed to explore my phone device and showed both memories, phone memory and external memory. Once you expand, all of your personal files will appear. 
[image]

You select a *Right Side* device:

[image]

Then both will appear:

[image]

From syncing settings, you can choose whether you want to make a backup operation, Left to Right/Right to Left, or sync in both ways. You can add more filtering settings e.g. files end with .mp4. 
[image]

---

Here I tried to do a left side sync for one of the folders from my phone memory `S0` to my pc:

[image]

After running an analysis;

[image]

After running Sync:
[image]

Here is the fin la result, the whole directory has been copied to my pc:

[image]

GoodSync Desktop's [price](http://www.goodsync.com/php/pums/rfprepay.php?lic=goodsync&lang=en): 30-40 USD.

Comment: +1 for providing a cross platform solution.
But I was looking for a simple dropbox like solution...
I guess this will work.

Comment: I'm not sure, but IMO I think having a dropbox-like app to monitor your whole device (internal and external memory) for changes might be a resource hog. Even for PC, dropbox only monitors one single main directory. Indexing such enormous number of files takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found what you are looking for : [Samba Filesharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba)

- Only works for windows though.
- Can be accessed as a share folder in your windows PC.
- Allows drag & drop
- Can Access External Storage ie SD Card

Requires rooting of Android Device but I think that is understood.